# A Program that can draw boxes on the Desktop?

Tags: windows-7, desktop

I'm looking for a program that can draw boxes around groups of icons on my desktop. Kind of a way to group similar items. Something that persists through a reboot as well. Has anyone seen anything like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[Stardock Fences](http://www.stardock.com/products/fences/)** is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Try [Stardock Fences](http://www.stardock.com/products/fences/), or if that's too overpowering, open up your wallpaper in paint and draw a few squares :P

Other options include Samurize and Rainmeter, which can also display information like CPU load and RAM usage.